# Uniqueness of sum of exponentials

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, real-numbers

I would like to know if there is an example of two non-trivial sets of real numbers (for the definition of "non-trivial" see below) $X=\{ x_1, \ldots x_n \}$ and $Y = \{ y_1, \ldots y_m \}$, with $m$ and $n$ positive (we may assume that both $X$ and $Y$ are specified in increasing order), such that

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n e^{x_i} = \sum_{j=1}^m e^{y_i}. $$

For me, the trivial case would be when every $x_i$ and $y_i$ is either zero or an integral power of $\log(e)$.

Comment: $e^{log(7)}+e^{log(2)}=e^{log(6)}+e^{log(3)}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be any finite set of non-trivial numbers.
Then simply define
$$y_1= \ln \left( \sum_{x \in X} e^x\right)$$
And $Y= \{ y_1 \}$ will satisfy your request.

But more can be done. Since $\exp : \Bbb{R} \longrightarrow \Bbb{R^+}$ is a bijection, you are simply asking wether there exist two finite sets of positive real numbers $X', Y'$ such that
$$\sum_{x \in X} x = \sum_{y \in Y} y$$
and this is obviously true.

Then simply take $X= \{ \ln x : x \in X' \}$ and $Y= \{ \ln y : y \in Y' \}$ and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

If you assume the numbers $x_i$ and $y_i$ are all algebraic (that is, they are roots of some polynomial with integer coefficients), then there are no such examples.  The stronger version of this statement where the $x_i$ and $y_i$ are algebraic complex numbers and you allow $X$ and $Y$ to be multisets (i.e., the $x_i$ and $y_i$ can repeat) is known as the [Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem).

Comment: Quite interesting

Comment: Well, from the Wikipedia article about the Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem it can be deduced that if the $x_i$ and $y_i$ are distinct algebraic numbers, then this is false, i.e. there can be no example like the one I am asking for. Am I missing something?

Comment: Er, that's what I meant.  It is true that sums of exponentials are unique.  I'll edit to clarify.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Then perhaps I should ask about an example with the $x_i$ and $y_i$ algebraic, but not necessarily distinct. Do you know one such example?

Comment: In the Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem, they don't need to be distinct (that's what I meant by allowing multisets).

Comment: But Baker's reformulation imposes this condition, i.e. that the exponents be distinct (again, according to Wikipedia). I am focusing on Baker's reformulation because I don't quite understand the original Lindemann-Weierstrass formulation.

Comment: The formulation I am giving here is a bit different from the formulation on Wikipedia.  Note that Wikipedia's formulation allows you to have rational (or even algebraic) numbers as coefficients in front of the exponentials; in the special case that these coefficients are integers, you recover my version where you are allowed to repeat copies of the same exponential.  (In fact, it is not too hard to show the integer-coefficient case implies the general case, which is why I said my statement "is" the Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem.)

Comment: Ah, OK, now I see. Where can I see the proof that this variant with integer coefficients and repeated exponentials implies the general case?

Comment: Going from integer coefficients to rational coefficients is very easy: you just multiply by a common denominator of all the coefficients.  Going from rational coefficients to algebraic coefficients is a bit harder, but it is essentially just the fact that if $x$ is algebraic over $F$ and $y$ is algebraic over $F(x)$, then $y$ is algebraic over $F$ (for any field $F$).

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot.